# C# ASP.NET can not reload web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, reload

i can not  reload the WebApplication project[image: reload the WebApplication], i got this message error [image: message error]

i moved the server to another place, so the IP is changed.

i already change the ip on IIS and WebApp config 
i already uninstall IIS and reinstall 
i already use aspnet_reggis -i

but still i, can not reload the WebApplication.

thanks you in advance

PS: i m sure is because the IP configuration. it work well at my home, now i bring the computer to office...it not work anymore....nothing change just the IP my home is not the same like IP in my office

Comment: Try to get write this error message in English. This can be helpful.

Comment: The message error is in French!

Comment: I'm an englishman in new yourk

Comment: Sory..the error said : The Project Application WebApp is configure for use IIS. the server web  ... is not found

Answer (score 1):

the error message says: the project web ESPTEMPS_WebApp is configured for IIS, the website is not found.

You most likely need to configure your IIS for your website.

here's a helpful link to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cek8kw6e.aspx

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

Your application is configured to work with IIS, in your case, IIS is not installed in your system or maybe the developer used IIS Express when developing. (You need to install VS 2010 sp1 to get IIS Express 7.5 integration with VS)

What you can do is:

Close your solution and open the csproj file in notepad (of the project that is giving problems)

Find and set these values:

```
<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
<UseIISExpress>False</UseIISExpress>
```

Then reopen your solution again with visual studio. You will be able to debug with the web developer web server.

Comment: i know it work, but i wanna to use IIS. it is the same Server/Computer only i move to another office, that change the IP...all is the same

Comment: Sounds like a network issue then. It looks like the server is: 172.18.1.110 port 4000. If you moved and your IP has changed you need to go to the project properties and change the server IP. Also, go to IIS and check the bindings to make sure IIS is not listening on the old IP.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good reference for you. It will walk your through set of steps to help you configure your IIS. Here is the [link](http://ukchill.com/technology/setting-up-a-web-project-environment-in-visual-studio-2010-to-allow-debugging-using-both-iis7-and-the-development-web-server/). Please ignore the steps that are not applicable to you. But basic idea is:

- Open Project Properties and go to Web tab
- Select local IIS web server. If it is already selected, it will show you a virtual directory. If it doesn't already show selected, then mention the virtual directory.